# I want to insert a column to table that read every raw before that and multiple that

Tags: python, pandas

Summery:
I Want to make the Milk Price Column Get value from price table and multiple it in used milk but  dont know how i just multiple the first item .

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

recpies = pd.read_csv('recipes_muffins_cupcakes.csv')
prices = pd.read_csv('recipes_price.csv')
rdf = pd.DataFrame(recpies)
pdf = pd.DataFrame(prices)

#recpies ['Milk_Price'] = rdf.iloc[:,-1]*pdf.loc[1]['Price']
mo = str(len(recpies))
res=""
for i in mo:

    res = rdf.loc[int(i)]['Milk'] * pdf.loc[1]['Price']
rdf.insert(3,"Milk Price",res,allow_duplicates=True)

print(rdf)
print(pdf)
```

this is My Code;
and this is output

```
Type  Flour  Milk  Milk Price  ... Egg  Baking Powder  Vanilla  Salt
0    Muffin   0.55  0.28        5.04  ...   5          0.002    0.000     0
1    Muffin   0.47  0.24        5.04  ...   9          0.001    0.000     0
2    Muffin   0.47  0.23        5.04  ...   4          0.001    0.000     0
3    Muffin   0.45  0.11        5.04  ...   8          0.001    0.000     0
4    Muffin   0.50  0.25        5.04  ...   5          0.002    0.001     0
5    Muffin   0.55  0.27        5.04  ...   5          0.002    0.001     0
6    Muffin   0.54  0.27        5.04  ...   5          0.002    0.000     0
7    Muffin   0.47  0.26        5.04  ...   4          0.001    0.000     0
8    Muffin   0.50  0.17        5.04  ...   6          0.001    0.000     0
9    Muffin   0.50  0.17        5.04  ...   4          0.001    0.000     0
10  Cupcake   0.39  0.00        5.04  ...  14          0.001    0.001     0
11  Cupcake   0.42  0.21        5.04  ...   8          0.003    0.000     0
12  Cupcake   0.34  0.17        5.04  ...   5          0.002    0.001     0
13  Cupcake   0.39  0.13        5.04  ...  10          0.001    0.001     0
14  Cupcake   0.38  0.15        5.04  ...   8          0.000    0.001     0
15  Cupcake   0.42  0.18        5.04  ...   5          0.001    0.000     0
16  Cupcake   0.36  0.14        5.04  ...  11          0.002    0.001     0
17  Cupcake   0.38  0.15        5.04  ...   6          0.001    0.001     0
18  Cupcake   0.36  0.16        5.04  ...   9          0.001    0.001     0
19  Cupcake   0.34  0.17        5.04  ...  13          0.000    0.000     0

[20 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Show a sample of the desired output and maybe samples of the input tables.

Comment: i am sorry that i told bad but i want to make a Milk Price column that get info from Milk and Multiple into Price from Price table but i dont know how ,

Comment: It would be useful (and would prompt an answer to your question) if you provided a (reduced) sample of each the two datasets, This would mean that a solution can be demonstrated without much effort.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below multiplies `Milk` by `Milk Price`, and puts the result in `milk_times_price`. Is this the desired behaviour?

Briefly, the operation is:

```
df['milk_times_price'] = df['Milk'] * df['Milk Price']
```

[image]

Complete example:

```py
#Example data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['Muffin', 0.55, 0.28, 5.04, 5, 0.002, 0.000, 0],
        ['Muffin', 0.47, 0.24, 5.04, 9, 0.001, 0.000, 0],
        ['Muffin', 0.47, 0.23, 5.04, 4, 0.001, 0.000, 0],
        ['Muffin', 0.45, 0.11, 5.04, 8, 0.001, 0.000, 0],
        ['Muffin', 0.50, 0.25, 5.04, 5, 0.002, 0.001, 0],
        ['Muffin', 0.55, 0.27, 5.04, 5, 0.002, 0.001, 0],
        ['Muffin', 0.54, 0.27, 5.04, 5, 0.002, 0.000, 0],
        ['Muffin', 0.47, 0.26, 5.04, 4, 0.001, 0.000, 0],
        ['Muffin', 0.50, 0.17, 5.04, 6, 0.001, 0.000, 0],
        ['Muffin', 0.50, 0.17, 5.04, 4, 0.001, 0.000, 0],
        ['Cupcake', 0.39, 0.00, 5.04, 14, 0.001, 0.001, 0],
        ['Cupcake', 0.42, 0.21, 5.04, 8, 0.003, 0.000, 0],
        ['Cupcake', 0.34, 0.17, 5.04, 5, 0.002, 0.001, 0],
        ['Cupcake', 0.39, 0.13, 5.04, 10, 0.001, 0.001, 0],
        ['Cupcake', 0.38, 0.15, 5.04, 8, 0.000, 0.001, 0],
        ['Cupcake', 0.42, 0.18, 5.04, 5, 0.001, 0.000, 0],
        ['Cupcake', 0.36, 0.14, 5.04, 11, 0.002, 0.001, 0],
        ['Cupcake', 0.38, 0.15, 5.04, 6, 0.001, 0.001, 0],
        ['Cupcake', 0.36, 0.16, 5.04, 9, 0.001, 0.001, 0],
        ['Cupcake', 0.34, 0.17, 5.04, 13, 0.000, 0.000, 0]
    ],
    columns=['Flour', 'Milk', 'Milk Price', 'Egg', 'Baking', 'Powder', 'Vanilla', 'Salt']
)

df['milk_times_price'] = df['Milk'] * df['Milk Price']
df
```